# TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null PHP/AJAX chat

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm following an PHP/AJAX chat tutorial in the "Building Responsive Web Applications AJAX and PHP" book and i'm encountering the following error :

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
```

I'm fairly sure it's refering to this code in the javascript file :

```
function readMessages(){
    var response = XmlHttpGetMessage.responseText;

    if(response.indexOf("ERRNO") >= 0 || response.indexOf("error:")>= 0 || response.length==0){
        throw(response.length == 0 ? "Void server response." : response);
    }   

    response = XmlHttpGetMessage.responseXML.documentElement;

    clearChat = response.getElementByTagName("clear").item(0).firstChild.data;

    if(clearChat == "true"){
        $("#scroll").html("");
        lastMessageID = -1;
    }

    idArray = response.getElementByTagName("id");
    //nameArray = response.getElementByTagName("name");
    timeArray = response.getElementByTagName("time");
    messageArray = response.getElementByTagName("message");

    displayMessages(idArray, nameArray, timeArray, messageArray);

    if(idArray.length>0){
        lastMessageID = idArray.item(idArray.length - 1).firstChile.data;
        setTimeout("requestNewMessages();", updateInterval);
    }
}
```

This is the ajax request I send :

```
if(cache.length>0){
    params = cache.shift();
}else{
    params="mode=RetrieveNew" +
           "$id=" +lastMessageID;
}

XmlHttpGetMessage.open("POST", chatURL, true);
XmlHttpGetMessage.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XmlHttpGetMessage.onreadystatechange = handleRecievingMessages;
XmlHttpGetMessage.send(params);
```

And here is the PHP file :

```
<?php
require_once('init.php');


$mode = $_POST['mode'];
id=0;
$chat = new Chat();
if($mode=='SendAndRetrieveNew'){
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if($user_id != '' && $message != '' && $color != ''){
        $chat->postNewMessage($user_id, $message, $color);
    }
}elseif($mode=='DeleteAndRetrieveNew'){
    $chat->deleteAllMessages();
}elseif($mode=='RetrieveNew'){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
}

if(ob_get_length()){ob_clean();}

header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . 'GMT'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

echo $chat->getNewMessages($id);
?>
```

Here is the handle receiving messages function
    function handleRecievingMessages(){

```
    if(XmlHttpGetMessage.readyState == 4){
        if(XmlHttpGetMessage.status == 200){
                try{

                    readMessages();
                }catch(e){
                    displayError(e.toString());
                }   
            }else{
                displayError(XmlHttpGetMessage.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally my getNewMessages function

```
public function getNewMessages($id=0){
            $queryArray = array($id);
             if($id>0){ 
        //only get the new messages
        $query = 
        ' SELECT message_id, user_id, message, DATE_FORMAT(posted_on, "%H:%i:%s") 
        AS posted_on FROM chat WHERE message_id > ' 
        . $id . 
        ' ORDER BY message_id ASC'; 
        }else{
        //on the first load only retrieve the last 50 messages from server
        $query = 
        ' SELECT message_id, user_id, message, posted_on 
        FROM (SELECT message_id, user_id, message,s DATE_FORMAT(posted_on, "%H:%i:%s") 
        AS posted_on FROM chat ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 50) AS Last50 
        ORDER BY message_id ASC';
        } 

            $query = $this->_database->_link->prepare($queryString);
            $query->execute();

            $response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
        $response .= '<response>';  
        $response .= $this->isTableCleared($id); // output the clear flag

        // if we have any results, loop through all the fetched messages to build the result message
        if($query->rowCount()){ //get number of rows in a result, aka check for results
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ //get results as an associative array
        $id = $row['message_id'];
        $userName = $row['user_id'];
        $time = $row['posted_on'];
        $message = $row['message'];
        $response .= '<id>' . $id . '</id>' . 
                     '<color>' . $color . '</color>' . 
                     '<time>' . $time . '</time>' . 
                     '<name>' . $userName . '</name>' . 
                     '<message>' . $message . '</message>';
      }

      $query->close(); // close the database connection
    }
    $response .= '</response>';
    return $response;
        }
```

When I debug with firebug i get the following text response :

```
    "<br /> <b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting T_FUNCTION in `<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\thinkaztech\includes\chat.class.php</b> on line <b>93</b><br /> "`
```

However I do not have a line 93?

I'm not sure what the error is, i'm connected to the database just fine and my chat.class.php file seems to be being called correctly. Thanks for any helpful advice in advance!

Comment: It looks like an xml document isn't being returned. inspect the response using javascript debugging tools.

Comment: Okay so I went through a whole list of errors and fixed them now the responseXML is null

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo:

```
params="mode=RetrieveNew" +
       "$id=" +lastMessageID;
        ^ should be a & not a $
```

Comment: Thanks, still have the issue though

Comment: Can you include the section of code where you use `response = XmlHttpGetMessage.responseXML.documentElement;`? That seems pertinent, yes?

Comment: Sure, I edited the line so it now includes the code from the whole function

Comment: What is handleRecievingMessages? I assume it is checks that `readyState==4` then calls `readMessages`, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong there. Is `$chat->getNewMessages($id);` responding with xml? Does it do something like this? http://darklaunch.com/2009/05/23/php-xml-encode-using-domdocument-convert-array-to-xml-json-encode

Comment: I can see in the book that they are using json encoding, but you are using xml.

Comment: In this book, they are definitely using XML, I have included the getNewMessages php function in my original post.

Comment: Do you have any messages that include the characters `<` or `>`?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with what you have so far. Sorry :(

Comment: No problem, thanks for the support :/ I just really don't know whats wrong, I've just been sat here staring at it :)

Comment: Just edited in an error the request returns.

Comment: That's a syntax error. If you use a code editor like SublimeText, or anything that does syntax highlighting, you will find it easily.

Comment: I guess its time to upgrade from notepad++ :)